# vb.net how to detect if an email is undeliverable in a win form program

Tags: vb.net, email

I have the following code:

```
Public Function VerstuurMail(ByVal strFrom As String, ByVal strTo As String, ByVal strSubject As String, ByVal strBody As String, ByVal strMailSMTP As String, ByVal MailUser As String, ByVal MailPassword As String, ByVal MailPort As Integer, Optional ByVal AttachmentFiles As String = "") As String

    Try

        'create the mail message
        Dim mail As New MailMessage()

        Dim basicCredential As New NetworkCredential(MailUser, MailPassword)

        'set the addresses
        mail.From = New MailAddress(strFrom)
        mail.To.Add(strTo)

        'set the content
        mail.Subject = strSubject
        If File.Exists(strBody) = True Then
            Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(strBody, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1252))
            mail.Body = objReader.ReadToEnd
            objReader.Close()
        End If
        mail.IsBodyHtml = False

        'send the message
        Dim smtp As New SmtpClient(strMailSMTP)
        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network
        smtp.EnableSsl = True
        'smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        smtp.Credentials = basicCredential
        smtp.Port = MailPort

        Dim AttachmentFile As String() = AttachmentFiles.Split("*")
        For Each bestand In AttachmentFile
            If System.IO.File.Exists(bestand) Then
                mail.Attachments.Add(New Attachment(bestand))
            Else
                Call MessageBox.Show("File can't be found")
            End If
        Next

        'Dim userState As Object = mail
        'smtp.SendAsync(mail, userState)
        'AddHandler smtp.SendCompleted, AddressOf SendCompletedCallback

        smtp.Send(mail)
        mailSent = True

        smtp.Dispose()

    Catch ex As Exception
        mailSent = False
        Call MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & vbCrLf & "Didn't sent to: " & strTo & vbCrLf & " with extra error message:" & vbCrLf & ex.ToString)
    Finally

    End Try

    Return mailSent

End Function
```

This function is used in a program which reads a text file, with the parameters on one line, and is called as many lines there are. (in a loop)
This is working fine.

Now when the text file has a wrong email adress the function doesn't trow a error it just sent the email to nobody.

example: sent an mail to joe@gmail.com works, send an email to joe@hmail.com doesn't sent but doesn't give an error either.

I have googled but the examples said that I should use 'smtp.SendAsync(mail, userState)'
But then the program doesn't follow the loop anymore and no mails are being sent. I can't use the debugger and step through the code. It just jumps from one place to the other.

This is the other function:

```
   Private Sub SendCompletedCallback(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs)

    Dim mail As MailMessage = CType(e.UserState, MailMessage)

    'write out the subject
    Dim subject As String = mail.Subject

    'If e.Cancelled Then
    '    Call MessageBox.Show("Send canceled: " & Now & " token " & subject)
    '    MailLog &= "Send canceled" & vbCrLf
    'End If

    If Not e.Error Is Nothing Then
        Call MessageBox.Show("Foutmelding op: " & Now & " onderwerp " & subject & " met error: " & e.Error.ToString())
        MailLog = MailLog & "Niet verstuurd met als fout melding: " & e.Error.ToString() & vbCrLf
    Else
        'Call MessageBox.Show("Message sent at: " & Now)
        MailLog = MailLog & "Bericht verstuurd op: " & Now & vbCrLf
    End If

    mailSent = True

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance. I hope somebody can put me in the right direction.

Brian

Comment: How do you know which emails are "correct"? In other words, can you only send to `@gmail.com` accounts in your application or to any email address?

Comment: Well the program is used as a invoice sender, so when a client complains that he didn't get his invoice today. And the user checks his email adress in the other programs database, he can see that there was a spelling error. I used the gmail email adres as an example for a spellings error.

Comment: Are you asking how to detect if an email is undeliverable because the address does not exist? If so, you might want to edit the title to indicate as much.

Comment: Thank you OwenP. I have changed the title.

Answer (score 0):

This is a data issue, not an issue with the actual mechanism to send email. The best you can do is to use a regular expression to make sure the email address is valid per the rules of [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822), like this:

```
string email = txtemail.Text;
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^([\w\.\-]+)@([\w\-]+)((\.(\w){2,3})+)$");
Match match = regex.Match(email);

if (match.Success)
{
    Response.Write(email + " is valid.");
}
else
{
    Response.Write(email + " is invalid.");
}
```

Unfortunately for you, `joe@hmail.com` is a valid email address by the above logic, but is is not the intended `joe@gmail.com` address so it ends up in the wrong place. When it is discovered that it is the wrong email address, then changing the data to the right value is the only correct course of action.

---

> Note: Generally, you verify someone's email address when they register for a website, thus the system "knows" the email address is legitimate/correct because they successfully received an email and entered a verification code or clicked on a link that verified with the website that they did get the email. This solves most data issues (misspellings, incorrectly entered values, etc.).

Comment: Thank you Karl, but I was unclear in my asking. I have changed the question. It is not to be used on a website, but on a winform program. Where the program is to be added to an existing program, where the email adresses are entered in a phone confersation.

Comment: I have a spelling problem myself but I can only edit for 5 min. It is 'conversation'. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

After two full days of testing and searching I have found that when using:

```
    Dim userState As Object = mail
    smtp.SendAsync(mail, userState)
    AddHandler smtp.SendCompleted, AddressOf SendCompletedCallback
```

you should not close the smtpClient with smtp.Dispose()

The callback function kept getting the cancel error.

Also I used the backgroundworker for sending the many mails but the async is, in a way, a backgroundworker. So I had two backgroundworkers and that didn't work at all.

It took me two days.....

Brian